# ¿Como crear rowspan dinámico para reporte en Odoo 11 usando qweb?

Tags: odoo

Se desea cambiar el rowspan de un td usando el valor de una variable en un reporte qweb de Odoo 11 se ha intentado:

```
<t t-set="Contador" t-value="5"/>
```

luego en el td:

```
<td rowspan="Contador">Texto que ocupa varias filas según condiciones</td>
```

Pero no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder cambiar un atributo mediante una variable se debe:

```
<t t-set="Contador" t-value="5"/>
<td width="22%"  t-att-rowspan="Contador">Texto que ocupa varias filas según condiciones</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba Esto:

```
<td  t-att="['rowspan',Contador]" >Texto que ocupa varias filas según condiciones</td>
```

O intenta esta manera:

```
<t t-set="filas" t-value="rowspan='5'"/>
```

y

```
<td t-raw="filas">Texto que ocupa varias filas según condiciones</td>
```

No lo he probado, pero pienso que debería funcionar.